# Is there anyway to call dynamic object inside Slim middleware?

Tags: php, slim-3

I'm having a pure php source then i integrate Slim 3 inside the source.

In the index.php to init Slim app, i have required all class i have already defined and i also call to some member functions of some object inside the index.php. But when i come into the middleware to check some require information of request the include route file, it cause the problem that i cannot call to any function member, i think i was because of the use() on the function middleware.

So is there anyway to pass all of the object i created from classes into the middleware then the route can use() it?

Here is my middleware code:

```
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, $next) use ($global_api_key, $app) {
    $api_key = $request->getParam('apikey');
    $token = $request->getParam('token');
    if ($api_key == $global_api_key) {
        if ($token != ''){
          //do something...
        }
        else{
           require PATH_APP . '/init.php';
        }
        $response = $next($request, $response);
        return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    } else {
        $status = 400;
        $message = 'Bad request!';
        return $response->withStatus($status)->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')->write(json_encode($message));
    }
});
```

Here is my init.php file:

```
$app->group('/login', function (){
    $this->post('/device_login', function ($request, $response){
       //Call to an object from included class to get some $data
       ....
       $response->withStatus(200)->write(json_encode($data));
    });
});
```